How to assign function type that has different / additional arguments in typescript
// callbacks
const callback1 = (key: string, value: unknown) => {
    if (typeof value !== 'number' || Number.isNaN(value)) throw new Error('error ' + key)
    return value
}

const callback2 = (key: string, value: unknown, min: number, max: number = Infinity) => {
    if (typeof value !== 'number' || Number.isNaN(value)) throw new Error('error ' + key)
    if (value < min || value > max) throw new Error('error')
    return value
}

const callback3 = (key: string, value: unknown, something: number) => {
    if (typeof value !== 'number' || Number.isNaN(value)) throw new Error('error ' + key)
    if (value === something) throw new Error('error')
    return value
}

type Obj = { [P: string]: unknown }

const tesstobj: Record<string, unknown> = { one: 1, two: 'two' }


// main

const evaluate = <
    O extends Obj,
    F extends (key: string, val: unknown) => ReturnType<F> // <--
>(obj: O, prop: keyof O, vfunc: F) => {
    if (typeof prop !== 'string') throw new Error('error')
    return vfunc(prop, obj[prop])
}

const evaluate_two = <
    O extends Obj,
    F extends (key: string, val: unknown, ...args: unknown[]) => ReturnType<F> // <--
>(obj: O, prop: keyof O, vfunc: F , ...args: unknown[]) => {
    if (typeof prop !== 'string') throw new Error('error')
    return vfunc(prop, obj[prop], ...args)
}

evaluate(tesstobj, 'one', callback1) // good
evaluate(tesstobj, 'one', callback2) // error as expected



// below expression statements should not fail

evaluate_two(tesstobj, 'one', callback2) // should say missing `min` arg
evaluate_two(tesstobj, 'one', callback2, 1)  
evaluate_two(tesstobj, 'one', callback2, 1, 10)

evaluate_two(tesstobj, 'one', callback3, 1) // should say wrong type number instead of string 


In above snippet I need to able to pass callback1 / callback2 / callback3 to evaluate's  callback parameter along with its additional arguments. I tried achieve this in evaluate_two but it didn't work.
Error message
Argument of type '(key: string, value: unknown, min: number, max?: number) => number' is not assignable to parameter of type '(key: string, val: unknown, ...args: unknown[]) => number'.
  Types of parameters 'min' and 'args' are incompatible.
    Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'number'.

old playground link
Note: I know this can be achieved with help of union but its not dynamic, which I don't like.
Edit: Here is updated playground link now with clarifications in response to jcalz's comment.

What do you hope to express via unknown[] there? For function parameter types that's very restrictive and you would need something like never[] to make it type safe, or any[] to make it less restrictive.  See this SO question and this playground link. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer or find a suitable duplicate target. If not, what am I missing?

This playground link is how I'd do it but I don't understand why you expect a callback3 error when you're passing it exactly what it expects.

@jcalz Right,  I have updated post. (hope new snippet clarifies)

@jcalz SUPERB, that's what I was looking for, thank you!. (I got confused with callback3's last arg, thinking it was string not number, little bit got lost in playground).

@jcalz Can you submit you comment as answer, Ill accept it. Also if possible suggest me good question title to it helps any future wanderers.

I will write up an answer, but please [edit] to fix the callback3 example.

@jcalz 's solution did work but there was one issue, it was allowing additional args to be passed in evaluate_two's call even though its callback function took none as shown here in playground.
I managed to get it right by implementing a type that is similar to typescript's Parameters utility type but ignores starting 2 parameters (a1 and a2) of a function.
type ParametersFromIndex2<T extends (a1: any, a2: any, ...args: any) => any> = T extends (a1: any, a2: any, ...args: infer P) => any ? P : never

Full snippet
// callbacks
const callback1 = (key: string, value: unknown) => {
    if (typeof value !== 'number' || Number.isNaN(value)) throw new Error('error ' + key)
    return value
}

const callback2 = (key: string, value: unknown, min: number, max: number = Infinity) => {
    if (typeof value !== 'number' || Number.isNaN(value)) throw new Error('error ' + key)
    if (value < min || value > max) throw new Error('error')
    return value
}

const callback3 = (key: string, value: unknown, something: string) => {
    if (typeof value !== 'string') throw new Error('not string')
    return value
}

type R = Record<string, unknown>

const tesstobj: R = { one: 1, two: 'two' }

// below type is similar to typescript's `Parameters` type but its ignores startsing 2 args
// type Parameters<T extends (...args: any) => any> = T extends (...args: infer P) => any ? P : never
type ParametersFromIndex2<T extends (a1: any, a2: any, ...args: any) => any> = T extends (a1: any, a2: any, ...args: infer P) => any ? P : never

const evaluateNew = <
    O extends R,
    F extends (k: string, v: unknown, ...args: any) => ReturnType<F>,
>(obj: O, prop: keyof O, callback: F, ...args: ParametersFromIndex2<F>) => {
    if (typeof prop !== 'string') throw new Error('error')
    return callback(prop, obj[prop], ...args)
}

// testing callback1
evaluateNew(tesstobj, "one", callback1)
evaluateNew(tesstobj, "one", callback1)
evaluateNew(tesstobj, "one", callback1, "error")
evaluateNew(tesstobj, "one", callback1, 1)

// testing callback2
evaluateNew(tesstobj, "one", callback2)
evaluateNew(tesstobj, "one", callback2, 1)
evaluateNew(tesstobj, "one", callback2, 1, 10)
evaluateNew(tesstobj, "one", callback2, 1, 10, "error")
evaluateNew(tesstobj, "one", callback2, 1, 10, "error")
evaluateNew(tesstobj, "one", callback2, "error")

// testing callback3
evaluateNew(tesstobj, "one", callback3)
evaluateNew(tesstobj, "one", callback3, "good")
evaluateNew(tesstobj, "one", callback3, -1)
evaluateNew(tesstobj, "one", callback3, "good", "error")

// above passes all my requirements

Playground link

If you want to make sure that args matches the rest of the parameters for F after key: string, val: unknown, then you'll want another generic type parameter for the type of args:
const evaluate_two = <
    O extends Obj,
    A extends any[],
    F extends (key: string, val: unknown, ...args: A) => ReturnType<F> 
>(obj: O, prop: keyof O, vfunc: F, ...args: A) => {
    if (typeof prop !== 'string') throw new Error('error')
    return vfunc(prop, obj[prop], ...args)
}

Now you get the behavior you expect:
// const callback2: (key: string, value: unknown, min: number, max?: number) => number
evaluate_two(tesstobj, 'one', callback2) // error, too few arguments
evaluate_two(tesstobj, 'one', callback2, 1)
evaluate_two(tesstobj, 'one', callback2, 1, 10)

// const callback3: (key: string, value: unknown, something: string) => string
evaluate_two(tesstobj, 'one', callback3, 1) // error, number is not string

Playground link to code

ok I just noticed slight issue, it takes additional args as well, check this playground, Is it possible to solve this as well ?

There's nothing to "solve", it's the intended behavior of TypeScript. See documentation on function compatibility. If you really need to see something different here, you should consider opening a new question for it (after searching for existing ones). My intent when asking you in the comments if my approach met your needs was that you would actually check it thoroughly before telling me yes or no. At this point it's out of scope for the question as asked.

Thank you. I managed myself to get it working as explained here.

You can pass a callback, updated code
// callbacks
const callback1 = (key: string, value: unknown) => {
    if (typeof value !== 'number' || Number.isNaN(value)) throw new Error('error ' + key)
    return value
}

const callback2 = (key: string, value: unknown, min: number, max: number = Infinity) => {
    if (typeof value !== 'number' || Number.isNaN(value)) throw new Error('error ' + key)
    if (value < min || value > max) throw new Error('error')
    return value
}

const callback3 = (key: string, value: unknown, something: number) => {
    if (typeof value !== 'number' || Number.isNaN(value)) throw new Error('error ' + key)
    if (value === something) throw new Error('error')
    return value
}

type Obj = { [P: string]: unknown }

const tesstobj: Record<string, unknown> = { one: 1, two: 'two' }

const evaluate_two = <
    O extends Obj,
    F1 extends () => ReturnType<F1>
>(obj: O, prop: keyof O, vfunc: F1) => {
    if (typeof prop !== 'string') throw new Error('error')
    return vfunc();
}

evaluate_two(tesstobj, 'one', () => {
    callback1('one', tesstobj['one']);
})

evaluate_two(tesstobj, 'one', () => {
    const temp_min = -10;
    const temp_max = 10;
    callback2('one', tesstobj['one'], temp_min, temp_max);
})

evaluate_two(tesstobj, 'one', () => {
    const something = 100;
    callback3('one', tesstobj['one'], something);
})

Edit (updated answer as per @bogdanoff's comment):
// callbacks
const callback1 = (key: string, value: unknown) => {
    if (typeof value !== 'number' || Number.isNaN(value)) throw new Error('error ' + key)
    return value
}

const callback2 = (key: string, value: unknown, min: number, max: number = Infinity) => {
    if (typeof value !== 'number' || Number.isNaN(value)) throw new Error('error ' + key)
    if (value < min || value > max) throw new Error('error')
    return value
}

const callback3 = (key: string, value: unknown, something: number) => {
    if (typeof value !== 'number' || Number.isNaN(value)) throw new Error('error ' + key)
    if (value === something) throw new Error('error')
    return value
}

type Obj = { [P: string]: unknown }

const tesstobj: Record<string, unknown> = { one: 1, two: 'two' }

const evaluate = <
    O extends Obj,
    F extends (key: string, val: unknown) => ReturnType<F> // <--
>(obj: O, prop: keyof O, vfunc: F) => {
    if (typeof prop !== 'string') throw new Error('error')
    return vfunc(prop, obj[prop])
}

const evaluate_two = <
    O extends Obj,
    F extends (key: string, val: unknown, ...args: any[]) => ReturnType<F> // <--
>(obj: O, prop: keyof O, vfunc: F , ...args: any[]) => {
    if (typeof prop !== 'string') throw new Error('error')
    return vfunc(prop, obj[prop], ...args)
}

evaluate_two(tesstobj, 'one', callback1) 
evaluate_two(tesstobj, 'one', callback2) 
evaluate_two(tesstobj, 'one', callback3) 

just change args types from unknown[] to any[]. Hope this helps.

I appreciate the effort but this defeats the whole purpose. Just look at the very first call of evaluate_two( in your answer,  There is lots of repetition going on, like passing literal one in 3 places, 2 reference to tesstobj variable. if i want to change var name or value, i have to do it in multiple places  which I completely dislike here.

got it, just change args' type from unknown[] -> any[]. See edit in my answer above.

Thats close but not perfect, notice its not mandating parameters. check this playground for more.
